# I am trying to develop an XML Parser using C++. But encountering error on an enum value declared while returning

Tags: c++, xml

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project XMLParser ****

**** Internal Builder is used for build               ****
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o src\XMLParser.o ..\src\XMLParser.cpp
..\src\XMLParser.cpp: In member function 'XMLParseResult_t CXMLString::parse(std::string&, std::string&)':
..\src\XMLParser.cpp:155:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
g++ -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -o XMLParser.exe src\main.o src\XMLParser.o
Build complete for project XMLParser
Time consumed: 1656  ms.
```

Comment: error? or "warning : control reaches end of non-void function"

Answer (score 0):

Your method `parse()` should be returning a variable of type `XMLParseResult_t` but instead is not returning anything.

Either you are forgetting to `return` something or you are doing so conditionally within an if statement for instance. The compiler has no way of knowing if that if statement will always evaluate to true or not and so complains.

Comment: But I am getting an error while trying to return a variable of type XMLParseResult_t stating it cannot be resolved!

Comment: Then it is likely that you are not including the header for that type into your file. Could you post some code?